# $P=P^t$, proof with symmetric operators

Tags: linear-algebra

> 8. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional space over $\mathbb{R}$, with a positive definitive scalar product. Let $P:V\to V$ be a linear map such that $PP=P$. Assume that $P^tP=PP^t$.  Prove that $P=P^t$ ***Linear Algebra, Serge Lang***
>
> SOLUTION. We have $\langle P^t(v),P^t(v)\rangle=\langle v,PP^t(v)\rangle=\langle v,P^tP(v)\rangle=\langle P(v),P(v)\rangle$
>
> so we see that $\ker(P)=\ker(P^t)$ and
>
> $\langle P(v)-P^t(v),P(v)-P^t(v)\rangle=2(\langle P(v),P(v)\rangle-\langle P(v),P^t(v)\rangle)$.
>
> $\DeclareMathOperator{Im}{Im}V=\Im(P)\oplus\ker(P)$,so we can write $v=P(x)+w$, where $w\in\ker(P)=\ker(P^t)$. Then:
>
> $\langle P(v),P(v)\rangle=\langle P(x),P(x)\rangle$
>
> and
>
> $\langle P(v),P^t(v)\rangle=\langle P(x),P^tP(x)\rangle=\langle P(x),P(x)\rangle$
>
> The scalar product is positive definite, so $P(v)=P^t(v)$.***Solutions manual to Lang´s Linear Algebra, by Rami Sharkarchi***

**Questions:**

**1)** Given $\langle P^t(v),P^t(v)\rangle=\langle v,PP^t(v)\rangle=\langle v,P^tP(v)\rangle=\langle P(v),P(v)\rangle$, in which $P^tP=PP^t$ is an assumed property. Why is the theorem $P=P^t$ not proven with $\langle P^t(v),P^t(v)\rangle=\langle v,PP^t(v)\rangle=\langle v,P^tP(v)\rangle=\langle P(v),P(v)\rangle$? I guess $v$ is arbitrary and the property holds $P^tP=PP^t$  for all the $v\in V$

**2)** Why does the author write this $\langle P(v)-P^t(v),P(v)-P^t(v)\rangle=2(\langle P(v),P(v)\rangle-\langle P(v),P^t(v)\rangle)$? Is this later used in the proof? I could not see it.

**3)** Does this expression $\langle P(v),P(v)\rangle=\langle P(x),P(x)\rangle$ comes from the fact $P:V\to V$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: On 2 ) you can verify it yourself by using the definition of scalar product and the properties stated for $P$. It is a good exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) $\langle P^t(v),P^t(v)\rangle=\langle v,PP^t(v)\rangle=\langle v,P^tP(v)\rangle=\langle P(v),P(v)\rangle$ is not sufficient to deduce $P^t = P$ for example if we P was a unitary matrix ($P^tP = PP^t = I$) we would have $\langle P^t(v),P^t(v)\rangle=\langle v,PP^t(v)\rangle=\langle v,P^tP(v)\rangle=\langle P(v),P(v)\rangle$ but $P \neq P^t$.

For 2) $\langle P(v)-P^t(v),P(v)-P^t(v)\rangle=2(\langle P(v),P(v)\rangle-\langle P(v),P^t(v)\rangle)$ this formula combined with the two formulas $\langle P(v),P(v)\rangle=\langle P(x),P(x)\rangle$ and $\langle P(v),P^t(v)\rangle=\langle P(x),P(x)\rangle$ prove that $\langle P(v)-P^t(v),P(v)-P^t(v)\rangle = 0$ which implies that $P(v) = P^t(v)$.

Comment: Could please expand point 1)? I do not understand your example of unitary matrix. I have not covered them yet.

Comment: $A$ is a unitary matrix if $A\cdot A^t =A^t\cdot A= I$. It is clear that every unitary matrix will verified 1) but as we know some unitary matrix that not symmetric

Comment: $I^t=I$, where I is the identity matrix.

Comment: Yes, but A is not symmetric in general

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 3):

Using the decomposition of $v$:
\begin{align}
v = P(x) + w \Rightarrow \\
\langle P(v), P(v) \rangle 
&= \langle P(P(x)+w), P(P(x)+w) \rangle \\
&= \langle P^2(x)+ P(w), P^2(x)+ P(w) \rangle \\
&= \langle P^2(x), P^2(x) \rangle \\
&= \langle P(x), P(x) \rangle
\end{align}
where the linearity of $P$, $P(w) = 0$ and $P^2 = P$ was used.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I could not see it because I was completely Dec incentivize due to point 1)